# Spring Security Java NoSuchMethodException: SecurityConfig.<init>()

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

I am performing the configuration in my project with Spring Security based in Java config.

Only I'm having a problem initializing Spring Security, I'm using SecurityConfig.class class to initialize the appropriate settings, but the problem is that this class has a constructor that demanded a parameter.

I'm basing myself in the documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc

```
public class SecurityConfig implements ConfigAttribute {
....

//~ Constructors ==================

public SecurityConfig(String config) {
    Assert.hasText(config, "You must provide a configuration attribute");
    this.attrib = config;
}
....
}
```

SecurityApplicationContext.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.tiarebalbi.kupo.configuration.security")
public class SecurityApplicationContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Autowired
private KupoUserDetailsService userDetailService;

/**
 * @param auth {@link AuthenticationManagerBuilder}
 * @throws Exception {@link Exception} 
 */
@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .withDefaultSchema()
            .and()
        .userDetailsService(userDetailService)
        .passwordEncoder(new KupoPasswordEncoder());
}

@Override
@Autowired
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/public/**", "/recover-password", "/recover/**").permitAll()    
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login") 
            .loginProcessingUrl("/auth-verify")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .and()
        .rememberMe()
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .maximumSessions(this.env.getRequiredProperty("security.session.max", Integer.class))
            .expiredUrl("/login?expired");
}
}
```

Dispatcher Servlet Initializer:

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializerContext extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { SecurityConfig.class ,GlobalApplicationContext.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[] { WebApplicationContext.class, WebSocketApplicationContext.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

@Override
protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) {
    registration.setInitParameter("dispatchOptionsRequest", "true");
    registration.setAsyncSupported(true);
}


@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
}
}
```

ERROR:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2810)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2053)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1021)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:381)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:293)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:788)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:434)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:780)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:284)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1322)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:732)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:490)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart(JettyWebAppContext.java:280)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:155)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:118)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:342)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:100)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:290)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:69)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:564)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:360)
at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute(JettyRunMojo.java:168)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting the class as a SecurityConfig.class @Bean and adjusting settings AuthenticationManager

```
    /**
 * @return {@link SecurityConfig}
 */
@Bean
public SecurityConfig securityConfigBean() {
    SecurityConfig config = new SecurityConfig("kupo-security");
    return config;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param auth {@link AuthenticationManagerBuilder}
 * @throws Exception {@link Exception} 
 */
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authProviders().getDaoProvider());
}

@Bean
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return new ProviderManager(authProviders());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You trying to register SecurityConfig.class in application context. But as exception message says:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig.<init>()
```

When you add any class to your application context, Spring tries to instanciate them using default constructor. That means that there is no default constructor in SecurityConfig.

I also have no idea why do you try to register class in application context that doesn't mark with @Configuration annotation and doesn't have any @Bean annotation inside. If ou refer to:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration

you will see that in that tutorial they created class named SecurityConfig.
So I think you should create your own SecurityConfig and import exactly this one instead of org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig

Comment: I do not know if you check the function of SecurityConfig.class in the system but I did both ways creating an implementation and creating a bean definition.

At the moment I define it as a bean I get to have another problem which is the startup AuthenticantionManager.

  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, but found []

Comment: You saved a lot of hours. Thanks dude